# How to enable /dev/input/uinput?

Tags: android, touch, touchscreen

I'm trying to use touch screen with developer board running Android 2.2. I have manufacturer's instructions and I need to enable uinput process which should be visible in Android under /dev/input as uinput.

I have checked this using menuconfig:

```
CONFIG_INPUT_UINPUT: y/m
    Device Drivers --->
        Input Device Support --->
            Miscellaneous devices --->
                User level driver support
```

[image]

And the driver is already enabled but uinput is still not visible in /dev/input.
I have process uinput in /dev but it is owned by bluetooth.
Is there a way to install uinput process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that driver was looking in both places (/dev and /dev/input) so this wasn't necessary. In case someone still needs that file to be in /dev/input location you can create symlink by putting this at the end of init.rc file:

```
service ln /system/bin/ln -s /dev/uinput /dev/input/uinput
    user root
    group root
```